# Why is Intl.NumberFormat formatting 4 digits together on es-ES locale?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, internationalization

I'm trying to format a number using the **Intl.NumberFormat**.

I have checked [MDN WebDocs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) but I'm not able to get the response I guess it should return.

I'm formatting with spanish locale, and I want to get the point separator between thousands (using `useGrouping` option), however, I'm not getting it

- Expected result: 1.124,50 €
- Obtained result: 1124,50 €

```js
var sNumber = '1124.5'
var number = new Number(sNumber);

let  style = {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: "EUR",
            minimumFractionDigits: 2,
            useGrouping: true
        };

const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("es", style);

console.log(formatter.format(number));
```

Comment: Works like expected for me

Comment: That works as intended. In spanish locales you should write 1124,50€ but 11.124,50€. No grouping separator if there are only 2 groups and the first one would have only one member

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a feature of the Spanish formatter with 4-digit numerics (i.e. 1234.56).

Take a look at the below and run it:

```js
let  style = {
            style: 'currency',
            currency: "EUR",
            minimumFractionDigits: 2,
            useGrouping: true
        };
var formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("es", style);

console.log('Spanish (ES)');
console.log(formatter.format(1234.56));
console.log(formatter.format(12345.67));
console.log(formatter.format(123456.78));

formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat("de-DE", style);

console.log('German (de-DE)');
console.log(formatter.format(1234.56));
console.log(formatter.format(12345.67));
console.log(formatter.format(123456.78));
```

You will see that for 5-digit and above numbers, the Spanish formatter does indeed group the numbers as expected.

However, if you use a German formatter (`de-DE`), it correctly formats the 4-digit numeric.

Output:

```
Spanish (ES)
1234,56 €
12.345,67 €
123.456,78 €

German (de-DE)
1.234,56 €
12.345,67 €
123.456,78 €
```

Comment: If this is correct then that means the Amazon website for Spain is displaying it wrong when they write 1099 as 1.099. https://www.amazon.es/s?k=macbook+pro

Comment: The point here is that spanish institution "RAE" stablishes that group separator shouldn't be used for 4 integer digit numbers → https://www.rae.es/dpd/n%C3%BAmeros

Comment: This is not correct, the institution RAE stablishes is 'common' omit this separator. Is not a rule, I guess this rule is for the years (2024, instead 2.024) but I believe this is a bug. For example using prices of products its very weird mix numbers 1234,00 with 12.345,00.
I'm spanish, I wish Intl would fix this problem. i.e. amazon.es has fixed this and show the separator as expected with numebers of 4 digits. In my project I will do the workaround in my format number function if (locale === 'es-ES') locale = 'de-DE'. very weird but works as expected.