# intl.NumberFormat shows incorrect result for es-ES currency formatting

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I expect that output for es-ES and de-DE locale to be identical. (I asked my Spanish colleague to check his salary slip, and he confirms that there is indeed a decimal after thousand)

```
var number = 1000;
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number));
```

Results:

```
> "1.000,00 €"
> "1000,00 €"
```

Comment: Related: [Why is Intl.NumberFormat formatting 4 digits together on es-ES locale?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58430460/1983854)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Real Academia Española](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Spanish_Academy), the standard form in Spanish is to separate numbers in groups of three, separated with whitespace, if the number has *more* than four digits, i.e. at least five (Source: [https://www.rae.es/dpd/números](https://www.rae.es/dpd/n%C3%BAmeros), section 2.a, in Spanish).

Actually for numbers with five digits, your code gives me the same result for `de-DE` and `es-ES`, i.e. a separation with a dot:

```
let number2 = 10000
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number2));
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(number2));
```

gives me

```
10.000,00 €
10.000,00 €
```

The separation with dot seems not to be fully correct*, but that the grouping is not done for four-digit numbers seems to be in accord with the language rules of the RAE.

* Actually, also in German, according to the Duden you should use spaces rather than dots, see e.g. https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/zahlen-und-ziffern (in German).